# what is the forward slash and backslash together meaning in this javascript code

Tags: javascript, replace

```js
let big1 = ('B$ig d$reams pay$')
let big2 = big1.replace(/\$/gi, "")
console.log(big2)
```

what's the logic of using /\ in this case

Comment: `/` is the beginning of a regular expression and `\$` means a literal `$` (the \ prevents the `$` from being interpreted as having a special meaning).

Comment: The `/___/gi` is a regular expression literal. The `\$` inside it says to match a dollar sign literally (without the backslash in front of it, `$` has special meaning in regular experssions: it means "end of input" or "end of line" [if the `m` flag is used]).